# Copy SQL column from one to another maintaining ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to copy SQL long binary data from the "photo" column to the "id_photo_c" column.  Both columns are in separate tables.  A got a query to show exactly what I need, but unfortunately you cannot copy & paste outputs from the "Results Pane" of mssql.

I cannot copy the entire table from one to another, the new database has more rows (including some duplicates).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW1wD.png

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
[GroupTables].[dbo].[VisitorsAdvanced].[RecordNumber], [
GroupTables].[dbo].[VisitorsAdvanced].[photo], 
[SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm].[xxx_id_number_c], 
[SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm].[id_photo_c] 
FROM 
[GroupTables].[dbo].[VisitorsAdvanced], SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm] 
WHERE 
[GroupTables].[dbo].[VisitorsAdvanced].[RecordNumber] = [SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm].[xxx_id_number_c];
```

It seems like such a simple task (would take two clicks in Excel) - but I can't seem to get it to work.

This isn't a duplicate question.  I've seen similar questions on here, none of which describe how to simply copy data from one column to another.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, it seems like a simple update statement is all you need:

```
UPDATE [SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm]
SET [id_photo_c] = [SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm].[xxx_id_number_c]
FROM 
[GroupTables].[dbo].[VisitorsAdvanced]
INNER JOIN [SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm] 
ON
[GroupTables].[dbo].[VisitorsAdvanced].[RecordNumber] = [SugarCRM].[dbo].[contacts_cstm].[xxx_id_number_c];
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem then you should accept it so that other people will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this as straight-forward as updating the data in the `contacts_cstm` table?

```
UPDATE  contacts_cstm
  SET   id_photo_c = photo
  FROM  VisitorsAdvanced
  WHERE RecordNumber = xxx_id_number_c
```